# Is Hilbert's theorem generalizable to $H^3$ immersion in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The Hilbert theorem in differential geometry concerns the immersion of the hyperbolic plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is it valid for $H^3$  in $\mathbb{R}^4$?, and for all $H^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Comment: The proof shown in wikipedia employs the infinite area of the surface embedded in 3-dimensional real coordinate space to proof the theorem, would it be enough exchanging the area for the volume in the generalized case or is there some obstruction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that

- There is no isometric immersion of $\mathbb{H}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{2n-2}$,  even a local one. There is a local immersion into $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$. This is due to E. Cartan (1919-20) and T. Otsuki (1955).
- There is a complete isometric immersion of $\mathbb{H}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{4n-3}$. This was proved recently (1980s) by W. Henke.
- There is an isometric embedding of $\mathbb{H}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{6n-6}$. For $n=2$ this was found by D. Blanusa in 1955.

All of this, with references and proofs, can be found in Master's thesis [*Isometric Embeddings between Space Forms*](http://davidbrander.org/penn.pdf) by David Brander.

Specifically for the three-dimensional hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^3$:

- there is no local immersion into $\mathbb{R}^4$
- there is a local immersion into $\mathbb{R}^5$
- there is a complete immersion into $\mathbb{R}^9$
- there is an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{12}$

For all we know, $\mathbb{H}^3$ could have an isometric embedding into $\mathbb{R}^5$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^{12}$...

Comment: Thanks for the great reference @Normal human. I'm interested in the consequences for pseudo-Riemannian manifolds and already the non-existence result seems to indicate that since there is no local embedding into $\mathbb{R}^4$ there is no local embedding into Minkowski space either, no?